# My android java button shows up and animates but for some reason my code is never executed

Tags: java, android, button

I have a button in my android application.

```
 <Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Start scanning"
    android:id="@+id/bStartScan"
    android:enabled="true"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/third_person_button"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/StitchPCButton"
    android:longClickable="false" />
```

The button does animate and it does show up in my application, but none of teh code below is executed.

```
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.bStartScan:
            findViewById(R.id.bStartScan).setEnabled(false);
            ...
            ...
            break;
        default:
            Log.w(TAG, "Unrecognized button click.");
    }
}
```

My other buttons works just fine and I do not understand why this button refuses to fire.

Any ideas? Any questions?

Thank you so much in advance.

Comment: It would be diagnostically useful to add LOG calls in each of the cases. For example, in the one partial case shown, it is not obvious that there would be any visible effect.

Comment: Where are you setting the `OnClickListener` for that button? All I see is a button defined in XML and an `onClick()` method that is never connected to the button.

Comment: @Tanis.7x I noticed my mistake when i was copy pasting where I was setting my listeners. I had commented out the wrong lines so I never sat the listener for that button, but for a button I was not using. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<Button
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="Start scanning"
android:id="@+id/bStartScan"
android:layout_below="@+id/third_person_button"
android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/StitchPCButton"
/>
```

Use this and in your activity/Fragment 
onCreate() 
in

```
      Button startBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bStartScan);
startBtn.setonClicklistner(this);
```

Remove 
            findViewById(R.id.bStartScan) from switch() statement...

Comment: As @Tanis.7x suggested, I had commented out the wrong lines so I never sat the listener for that button, but for a button I was not using. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Add this line to your xml button code   ->  android:onClick="onClick"

Answer (score 0):

add this line in ur xml button tag:

```
android:onClick="myMethod"
```

and in the activity class add ur method like below:

```
public void myMethod(View v) 
{
  // write your code here
}
```